# Is it true that & operator is invented in c++

Tags: c++, c

I've read somewhere that the address-of operator `&` (or reference operator) was invented in C++ not in C and afterwards C also added this feature. I can't remember where I read about this, but is it true?

Comment: What is a "*reference operator*" supposed to be? I don't know which operator you are referring to. Please edit and clarify your question.

Comment: Reference operator? What's that?

Comment: Your question makes no sense...

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Forgive the terse responses. You are correct in that in c++ you can create variables of reference type. In c you cannot.

Comment: @RichardHodges he asked about operator  not about variable.

Comment: `&` is either the *address-of operator* or the *bitwise-and operator*. Both existed in C first and have nothing to do with references. If you are talking about the `&` after a type name, that is not an operator, but indicates a *reference type*, which does not exist in C at all.

Comment: @RichardHodges I see you can just write 'what's that' and get upvotes here :)

Comment: @uneven_mark yeah, I'm talking about "address-of operator". I use this every day but do not know what its name is :) Like I said, I just read somewhere about this and got curious.

Comment: @RoarRaizZer I suggest you change the naming in your question, then. I would vote to reopen in that case as the question would be clear. I cannot see how C would have worked without that operator, but maybe someone can give some interesting answer regarding the history. It would also certainly help if you could refer to where you got the claim from, if possible.

Comment: @uneven_mark Nah, nevermind. I don't care. If I can get my question closed right after i 've asked, what's the point then? I'm not curious anymore, thanks.

Comment: If you're talking about using `&` in the context of accepting parameters, yes. That was not available in C.

Comment: @uneven_mark once question is closed, it takes days to get it reopen, if it succeeds at all: all those who close-voted will not dater to reread edited question again, and a lot of people don't look at history and just not vote to repoen, thinking that there was surely a good reason to get the question closed.  We collectively at SO lost once more an opportunity to provide a good explanation to a valid question...

Comment: @RoarRaizZer Sorry that the question is closed for a terminology issue.  it would have been a nice opportunity to clarify :-) `&` behind a type is used for a [reference type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference).  This is new for C++.  It's not invented by C++ since older languages had a similar possibility for arguments, by declaring them as OUT arguments;  `&` before a variable is the [address-of operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/address-of-operator-amp?view=vs-2019).  THis already existend in C.

Comment: @Christophe Maybe I am just naive in thinking that the procedure actually works, but my impression was that I should close vote questions that are unclear immediately and vote for reopen them when the issue is resolved, with the idea being that the reopen votes will happen in a reasonable time frame. I do try to follow up on edits on all questions I voted on. But maybe I need to read a bit more on meta to decide whether my approach has a bad outcome in practice.

Comment: @uneven_mark No worry: It's not your fault. I think it's a design flaw of SO.  In fact there is a close vote "needs more focus" that encourages this behavior.  But voting to close doesn't give any chance to OP to improve the question.  This could only work if close-voters would get notified of an edit to give a second chance.

Comment: @problematicDude I understand, but I think the problem is that beginners often don’t know what to ask.

Comment: @RichardHodges I'm beginner because I don't know about C history? LOL

Answer (score 0):

In C, "&" can be "address of" operator or "bitwise-and" operator. They existed in C and they have no connection to references from C++. References don't exist in C, they exist only in C++.